# Windows 8 out of memory over time: Toke Paged consuming over 5GB

Tags: windows-8, memory, thinkpad

**Laptop:** Lenovo ThinkPad W530

As I leave my computer on for a day or so it starts to run out of memory. This continues until it freezes up completely.

I've read numerous articles that has lead me to the screen shot below, and `Toke` which consumes over 5GB of type paged. But all I can find on the tag `Toke` is highlighted in the screenshot... which isn't relevant to my setup.

Alternatively, although again not relevant, there was a workaround provided to someone by Microsoft:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/32f414c2-fefc-4ee3-94fa-231a18272234/toke-paged-pool-tag-consuming-high-amount-of-memory?forum=winserverTS

Can anyone provide some insight on what could be causing this?

**Note:** If you need additional information  I will pull it up asap. This has been an ongoing problem for the past 9+ months. Unfortunately I don't have the time for a wipe and load with our current development push.

[[image: Screen shot of various debugging tools]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKziT.png)

**Update:** I've found the culprit. Seems like it's `virtscrl.exe` which is Lenovo Auto Scroll. Others have had the same issue: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/virtscrl-exe-memory-leak/td-p/1193015

Looks like they have a new version (2.02) that isn't public yet. Link to download is here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62276273/gfvv05ww.exe

**Update 2:** It's been great ever since. Maxing out at around 37% memory usage. Woot!

[image]

Comment: Yes my friend, this problem is facing a lot of people who is using windows since windows Vista started, To solve your problem, check your task manager & terminate the program if its unneeded by pressing Ctrl+shift+esc , if you you have a doubt on it, make a screen shot of the task manager & uploaded to me.

Comment: I have my task manager open on the right side of that screen shot above. The highest usage listed is 77MB. Since I don't see any that match the 5GB used in `poolmon`, which should I remove that will fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this in the past and the toke tag is used by the Intel WIFI driver. So install the latest driver.

If this doesn't fix use [xperf to trace what causes the usage](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool). Install the [WPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), open a cmd.exe as admin and run this:

```
xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+POOL -stackwalk PoolAlloc+PoolFree+PoolAllocSession+PoolFreeSession -BufferSize 1024 -MinBuffers 256 -MaxBuffers 256 -MaxFile 512 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d pool.etl
```

capture 30s of the grow. Open the ETL with WPA.exe, add the Pool graphs to the analysis pane.

Put the pooltag column at first place and add the stack column. Now [load the symbols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) inside WPA.exe and expand the stack of the `Toke` tag. Now find other 3rd party drivers which use this tag. Look for driver updates

Comment: Interesting, it's just loading up the symbols now so I'll post back when I find out the 3rd party drivers using it. Thanks!

Comment: @user12834 have you found the driver. If not, zip and upload the ETL file. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Had to redo the .elt when memory usage was at capacity. Checking it right now to see if I can find the driver, if not I'll zip and upload it.

Comment: The new .elt file is 400 MB... old one was only 56 MB. Will post back after I review it.

Comment: Found it. virtscrl.exe. Apparently this is a problem other people are having: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/virtscrl-exe-memory-leak/td-p/1193015

Comment: Update above...

Comment: ok, I've seen this ,too in my German forum. Nice to hear that you're able to locate the cause with my favorite tool xperf.